# Flutter Screenshot package error on Syncfusion Charts

Tags: flutter, syncfusion-chart

I am using the screenshot package to get the image bytes and then add it to the pdf in syncfusion in flutter. While the screenshot package seems to be working for my own custom paint widgets, it keeps giving me this error when i try using it on a syncfusion chart widget.

Error:
No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting
from the context that was passed to
MediaQuery.of().
This can happen because the context used is not a
descendant of a View widget, which introduces a
MediaQuery.

This is an example of what the screenshot widget holds currently:

```
await screenshotController.captureFromWidget( Scaffold(
      body: SfCartesianChart(
      isTransposed: true,
      title: ChartTitle(text: 'Tonnes Moved by Week Days'),
      legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
      primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(title: AxisTitle(text: 'Week Days'), majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0), minorGridLines: MinorGridLines(width: 0)),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(title: AxisTitle(text: 'Amount of Tonnes'),majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0), minorGridLines: MinorGridLines(width: 0)),
      series: <ChartSeries>[
        // Stacked Bar Series
        StackedBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
          dataSource: getStackedBarData(),
          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.weekDay,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.barValue,
          name: 'Stacked Bar Series',
        ),
      
        // Line Series
        LineSeries<ChartData, String>(
          color: redAlertColor,
          dataSource: getLineData(),
          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.weekDay,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.lineValue,
          name: 'Line Series',
         
        ),
      ],
        ),
    ),
  ).then((Uint8List? values) async {
    sampleBarChartBytes = values!;
    saveListToFile(sampleBarChartBytes.toString(), "Testing");
  });
```

I have so far tried wrapping it in a materialapp, in a mediaquery. However, none of it has worked.
I have tried to separate it from the screenshot code and putting it in a separate widget, however I am unsure of why this error keeps coming up.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz of course it's open source. You can see the source code just like that. It's just that open source doesn't automatically mean that it has a free license. You are correct in stating that you need to pay for it

Comment: The term "open source" should not be corrupted to also mean "published source". That's a trick Microsoft tried to use a dozen years ago, and it didn't fly then and won't fly now.  "open source" is as defined by the Open Source Institute.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz you're right. My mistake. Apparently there is no universally agreed definition of it. https://opensource.org/ says one thing, https://opensource.com/ for example something else. It does seem that OSI is the most recognized so I was wrong.